# Trying to config ssl_ciphers

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to get perfect grade on https://www.immuniweb.com/ssl/
And the only one thing i need is to disable all CAMELLIA ciphers.

My config in NGINX was:

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-
ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-
POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-
GCM-SHA384;
```

So i just added `:!CAMELLIA` to the end of the row and now it's:

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-
ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-
POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-
GCM-SHA384:!CAMELLIA;
```

I restart nginx so many times, but CAMELLIA is still works.
I found similliar issue here [nginx seems to be ignoring ssl_ciphers setting](https://serverfault.com/questions/830169/nginx-seems-to-be-ignoring-ssl-ciphers-setting) and tried to stop it for few minutes, but it doesn't help.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you changing the configuration of the right server?

Comment: You was right. There are 4 config file in my bitrix virtual machine in different folder. I thought i found right one, cuz it affects some options like stamping, but for ciphers i had to edit other one.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are putting `ssl_ciphers` in the **http** block, so that it affects all servers:

```
http {
    ...
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ...
}
```

After that, restart nginx.

Comment: i'm using bitrix virtual machine and this syntax is illegal here

Comment: @Andrey If you have a problem, you need to be specific about it. What error message did you get.